# how do I merge two views

Tags: sql-server, query

I have basically two views named customerV and productV.

the SQL statement in the `customerV` view is :

```
SELECT     CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.SURNAME, CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.OTHER_NAME, CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.ADDRESS, RECIEVABLE.DATE, 
                      RECIEVABLE.PHONE#, RECIEVABLE.SERIAL#, RECIEVABLE.CHEQUE
FROM         CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION INNER JOIN
                      RECIEVABLE ON CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.PHONE# = RECIEVABLE.PHONE#
```

while the SQL statement in the `productV` view is :

```
SELECT     PRODUCT, MAKE, MODEL
FROM         PRODUCTV
```

I just want to create a new view called `serial_products` which would join all the columns of the two views into a single view called`serial_products`.

Comment: So what's the `JOIN` key going to be?  If you `JOIN` the views, we have to know how they are related.

Comment: I don;t know what database you are using, but in SQL server views that call other views can be performance killers, I would make a new view not combine them. What are you hoping to accomplish? The only thing I can see is to create a list of all products for all customers unless you have some other fields that we need inthe base tables to perform the join.

Comment: And if this database is not yet in production, you should fix the misspelled tablename from Recievable to Receivable. Trust me, the people who have to maintain this will appreciate it if you do so.  And phone number is a poor choice for a PK/FK as it changes (and they are reused sometimes for other people).

Answer (score 1):

Since you provide no common field to join on, I'm going to assume you want a  cross join, where every customer will be linked to every product.

```
SELECT     CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.SURNAME, CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.OTHER_NAME,
           CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.ADDRESS, RECIEVABLE.DATE,  RECIEVABLE.PHONE#,
           RECIEVABLE.SERIAL#, RECIEVABLE.CHEQUE, PRODUCT, MAKE, MODEL
FROM        CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION 
INNER JOIN  RECIEVABLE ON CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.PHONE# = RECIEVABLE.PHONE#
CROSS JOIN  PRODUCTV
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing much info on the database, am a newbie here. The Database am using is MSSQL server 2005. I have a Database on Access so I am trying to replicate that database on MSSQLserver 2005. We are moving from Access to MSSqlserver and we have an retail inventory management application interface that works with the Access Database built using C#. so I have to come up with a database that fits the access database including columns,primary keys,foriegn keys and all. The database columns/P.K/F.K are outlined below:

Comment: SELECT CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.ID, CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.SURNAME, CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.OTHER_NAME,CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.PHONE#, CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION.ADDRESS, GRN.DATE, GRN.PRODUCT, GRN.MAKE, GRN.MODEL, GRN.SERIAL#, RECEIVABLE.STAFF_NAME, RECEIVABLE.PHONE# AS Expr1, RECEIVABLE.DATE AS Expr2, RECEIVABLE.SERIAL# AS Expr3, RECEIVABLE.CHEQUE, MAKE_REGISTRATION.MAKE_ID, MAKE_REGISTRATION.MAKE AS Expr4,

Comment: MODEL_REGISTRATION.MODEL_ID, MODEL_REGISTRATION.MODEL AS Expr5, PRODUCT_REGISTRATION.PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_REGISTRATION.PRODUCT AS Expr6,STAFF_REGISTRATION.STAFF_ID, STAFF_REGISTRATION.STAFF_NAME AS Expr7, SELLING_PRICE.PRODUCT AS Expr8,SELLING_PRICE.MAKE AS Expr9, SELLING_PRICE.MODEL AS Expr10, SELLING_PRICE.PRICE

Comment: FROM MAKE_REGISTRATION INNER JOIN GRN ON MAKE_REGISTRATION.MAKE = GRN.MAKE INNER JOIN MODEL_REGISTRATION ON GRN.MODEL = MODEL_REGISTRATION.MODEL INNER JOIN PRODUCT_REGISTRATION ON GRN.PRODUCT = PRODUCT_REGISTRATION.PRODUCT INNER JOIN RECEIVABLE ON GRN.SERIAL# = RECEIVABLE.SERIAL# INNER JOIN SELLING_PRICE ON MAKE_REGISTRATION.MAKE = SELLING_PRICE.MAKE INNER JOIN STAFF_REGISTRATION ON RECEIVABLE.STAFF_NAME = STAFF_REGISTRATION.STAFF_NAME CROSS JOIN CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION

Comment: Now I want to connect the GRN table to Selling_price Table, How do i create a relationship between this two tables using the following sql statements on the access database?          SELECT [CUSTOMER REGISTRATION].SURNAME, [CUSTOMER REGISTRATION].[OTHER NAME], [CUSTOMER REGISTRATION].ADDRESS, RECEIVABLE.Date, RECEIVABLE.PHONE, RECEIVABLE.SERIAL, RECEIVABLE.CHECK, GRN.PRODUCT, GRN.MAKE, GRN.MODEL, [SELLING PRICE TABLE].PRICE, RECEIVABLE.STAFF

Comment: FROM (([CUSTOMER REGISTRATION] INNER JOIN RECEIVABLE ON [CUSTOMER REGISTRATION].[PHONE NO] = RECEIVABLE.PHONE) INNER JOIN GRN ON RECEIVABLE.SERIAL = GRN.SERIAL) INNER JOIN [SELLING PRICE TABLE] ON (GRN.PRODUCT = [SELLING PRICE TABLE].PRODUCT) AND (GRN.MAKE = [SELLING PRICE TABLE].MAKE) AND (GRN.MODEL = [SELLING PRICE TABLE].MODEL);

Comment: I hope this all makes sense because am just a programmer not a database Admin and am trying to build an Interface on visual studio which would retrieve information like the one on the access database. Thanks so much its nice coming to this site.

Comment: @Peter Put all those comments into your question, please.  They don't belong as comments, but they are material to  your problem.

Comment: @JNK sorry my mistake. yes its related to the other question but here i had created two views to see if i could join the columns of the two seperate view so that it shows the whole columns into one.